# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Posts_Authors_AuthorId"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I successfully built migrations, and I am now trying to update the database with my models in Asp.net core but it keeps giving me this error

"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Posts_Authors_AuthorId". The conflict occurred in database "MediumDb", table "dbo.Authors", column 'AuthorId'.
The statement has been terminated."

This is what the code in my Post class looks like

namespace Medium.Api.Entities
{
public class Post
{
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }

```
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int NoOfClaps { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }


    public string Image { get; set; }

   // public string Video { get; set; }

    public Author Author { get; set; }   

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
```

while the code in my Author class says this
namespace Medium.Api.Entities
{
public class Author
{
public int  AuthorId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

```
    public IQueryable<Post> Posts { get; set; }

}
```

}

This is my DbContext configuration
{
public class MediumApiContext : DbContext
{
public MediumApiContext(DbContextOptions options)
: base(options)
{

```
        //  Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
  
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public DbSet<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
            .HasKey(a => a.AuthorId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
            .HasMany(a => a.Posts)
            .WithOne(p => p.Author);


        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .ToTable("Posts");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Author)
        .WithMany(a => a.Posts);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
         .Property(p => p.CreatedDate)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasColumnType("Date")
         .HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()");
       
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
          .Property(p => p.Title)
          .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .Property(p => p.NoOfClaps)
            .IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
         .Property(p => p.Content)
         .IsRequired();
```

I don't know where I seem to be getting it all wrong. Please

Answer (score 0):

We Use FK for data integrity right now you have FOREIGN KEY with Author Table so :

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Posts_Authors_AuthorId". The conflict occurred in database "MediumDb", table "dbo.Authors", column 'AuthorId'. The statement has been terminated."

This means that when you create a Post, you must give an Author_ID that is on the Author table